# Use for loop to create dataframes from a list

Tags: python, pandas

Python/Pandas beginner here. I have a list with names which each represent a csv file on my computer. I would like to create a separate pandas dataframe for each of these csv files and use the same names for the dataframes. I can do this in a very inefficient way by creating a separate line of code for each name in the list and adding/removing these lines of code manually as the list changes over time, something like this when I have 3 names Mark, Frank and Peter:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'

Mark = pd.read_csv(path+"Mark.csv")
Frank = pd.read_csv(path+"Frank.csv")
Peter = pd.read_csv(path+"Peter.csv")
```

Problem is that I will usually have a dozen or so names and they change frequently, so this is not very efficient. Instead I figured I would keep a list of the names to update when needed and use a for loop to do the rest:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'
names = ['Mark','Frank','Peter']

for name in names:
    name = pd.read_csv(path+name+'.csv')
```

This does not produce an error, but instead of creating 3 different dataframes Mark, Frank and Peter, it creates a single dataframe 'name' using only the data from the first entry in the list. How do make this work so that it creates a separate dataframe for each name in the list and give each dataframe the same name as the csv file that was read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it creates a single dataframe 'name' using only the data from the first entry in the list.

It uses the *last* entry, because each time through the loop, `name` is replaced with the result of the next `read_csv` call. (Actually, it's being replaced with one of the value from the list, and *then* with the `read_csv` result; to avoid confusion, you should use a separate name for your loop variables as your outputs. Especially since `name` doesn't make any sense as the thing to call your result :) )

> How do make this work

You had a list of input values, and thus you want a list of output values as well. The simplest approach is to use a list comprehension, describing the list you want in terms of the list you start with:

```
csvs = [
    pd.read_csv(f'{path}{name}.csv')
    for name in names
]
```

It works the same way as the explicit loop, except it builds a list automatically from the value that's computed each time through. It means what it says, in order: "`csvs` is a list of these `pd.read_csv` results, computed once `for` each of the `name` values that is `in names`".

Answer (score 3):

`name` here is the variable used to iterate over the list. Modifying it won't make any noticable changes.

```py
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'
names = ['Mark','Frank','Peter']
dfs = []

for name in names:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(path + name + '.csv'))

# OR
dfs = [
    pd.read_csv(path + name + '.csv')
    for name in names
]
```

Or, you can use a `dict` to map the name with the file.

```py
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'
names = ['Mark','Frank','Peter']
dfs = {}

for name in names:
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(path + name + '.csv')

# OR
dfs = {
    name : pd.read(path + name + '.csv')
    for name in names
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:
If you know the names of all your csv files you can edit you code and only add a list to hold all your files.
Example

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'
names = ['Mark','Frank','Peter']
dfs = []

for name in names:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(path+name+'.csv')
```

Otherwise, you can look for all the files with csv extension and open all of them using `listdir()`

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Names'
files = os.listdir(path)
dfs = []
for file in files:
    if file[-3:] == "csv":
        dfs.append(pf.read_csv(path + file))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for name in names:  
    globals()[name] = pd.read_csv(path+name+'.csv')
```